# How to Create an animation tool from the following prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I was recently asked this question: How to approach this problem? Create a tool that will allow designers to configure animations. In order to facilitate this, implement an AnimationSequence in JavaScript that can render these animations.

For example, if a designer wanted to configure the filling of a bar element, the usage of AnimationSequence would look something like this

```
var barSequence = new AnimationSequence(bar, [
  [100, { width: '10%' }],
  [200, { width: '20%' }],
  [200, { width: '50%' }],
  [200, { width: '80%' }],
  [300, { width: '90%' }],
  [100, { width: '100%' }]
]);

barSequence.animate();
```

where the first element of each step in the sequence is the number of milliseconds until the step occurs and the second element is an object containing any number of CSS properties.

How would you implement an AnimationSequence?

Comment: if you want jQuery i think it would be easier to implement something like `barSequence = $(selection).AnimationSequence({ /*...*/ });`, the prototype would need to inject jQuery anyway

Comment: You should have a look at [`Web Animations`](https://w3c.github.io/web-animations/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to build a queue system then call each animation frame based on the first value. So something like this...

```
var AnimationSequence = function(elem, opts) {
    this.element = (typeof elem == "object") ? elem : $(elem); //jQuery
    this.options = opts;
    this.queue = [];
    this.timer = 0;
    this.init(opts);
}
AnimationSequence.prototype = {
    init: function(opts) {
        var that = this;
        for(var i = 0, l = opts.length; i < l; i++) {
            this.queue.push({delay: opts[i][0], command: opts[i][1]});
        }
        this.deQueue();
    },
    deQueue: function() {
        if(this.queue.length) {
            var animation = this.queue.shift(),
                that = this;
            this.timer = setTimeout(function() {
                that.element.animate(animation.command, function() {
                that.deQueue();
                });
            }, animation.delay);
        }
    }
};
$(function() {
    var barSequence = new AnimationSequence(".bar", [
        [100, { width: '10%' }],
        [200, { width: '20%' }],
        [200, { width: '50%' }],
        [200, { width: '80%' }],
        [300, { width: '90%' }],
        [100, { width: '100%' }]
    ]);
});
```

Obviously you would have the html...

```
<div id="bar-holder">
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

And Css...

```
#bar-holder {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.bar {
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
}
```

Working jsfiddle example... https://jsfiddle.net/kprxcos4/
Obviously you might want to beef it up a bit, but that is the start of an animation queue system that can handle arguments and custom fields.

Comment: If you want to trigger the animation on a certain event remove the "this.deQueue()" call from the init function and call that function on your event, like... $(".click").click(function() { barSequence.deQueue(); });

Comment: Thanks so much! :)

Comment: My pleasure, marking it as the answer, or an upvote would be nice ;)

Comment: It wont allow me :( I will once me repo is higher I guess